# Connecting to engine in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an engine in SQLAlchemy but I'm getting the following error:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 (923) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: SELECT schema_name()]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

I have tried the following, using the strings userid (`uid`), password (`pwd`) and DSN (`dsn`):

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

params = (
    f"DSN={dsn};"
    f"UID={uid};"
    f"PWD={pwd}"
    )
 params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
 con = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}").connect()
```

I also tried supplying the direct string

`f"mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{pwd}@{dsn}"`

which gives the same error.

I'm assuming something is going wrong in the way I'm creating the url.

If it helps, I have successfully made the connection using pyodbc by doing the following:

```py
con = pyodbc.connect(
    f"DSN={dsn};"
    f"UID={uid};"
    f"PWD={pwd}"
  )
```

Comment: hmm, you are using mssql+ but the error is oracle related. you should probably do something about that

Comment: Could you please clarify? I'm relatively new to SQL so don't have your knowledge

Comment: The error you're getting mentions Oracle which is another database provider. Your tags are sql server. And finally f"mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{pwd}@{dsn}" mentions mssql which is sql server. So it looks like you're mixing two different server providers here.